# Why can't I console log data from my flask application? I am using jinja

Tags: python, html, flask

I am trying load data into my flask page, and console log it, however I keep getting the below error

```
VM165:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:13
```

These are the code snippets from my .py and .html

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify, request, redirect
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    json_file = open("/Users/-------/Documents/GitHub/Geospatial-Opportunities-for-Supermarkets/supermarket_locations/longos_locations.json", "r", encoding ="utf-8")
    data = json.load(json_file)
    json_file.close
    return render_template("index.html", data = data)
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Supermarkets in Toronto</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.0-rc.3/dist/leaflet.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/css/style.css">
  <script> var data = '{{data}}'; </script>
</head>
```

Comment: https://sopython.com/canon/93/render-string-in-jinja-to-javascript-variable/

Comment: @VorsprungdurchTechnik still not working

Comment: Don't put the quotes around it. Are you doing just `var data = {{ data|tojson }};`?

Comment: Is this full error message? Do you use any JavaScript code which uses this `data` ?

Comment: @VorsprungdurchTechnik Yes, that is exactly what I did, inside a script tag inside the head tag

Comment: Just now I tried to reproduce the issue, but the code snippets you have shown worked well.

Comment: @furas no I don't

Comment: @mrEvgenX Strange

Comment: Yes, @mrEvgenX this is working for me too.

Comment: if you don't use `data` with any JavaScript code then template is OK and it should work. Only JavaScript could try to get data and has problem. But I see `leaflet.css` so maybe you use [leaflet map](https://leafletjs.com) which loads some JavaScript code and it needs `data` and it makes problem.

Comment: @furas I tried changing the variable name and it still isn't working

Comment: maybe you have two files `index.html` and you edit one file but template loads second file - and this file load javascript which needs `data` but it can't find it. Do you have other HTML files?

Comment: @furas Nope just one

Comment: @furas So strange, that even when I say ```var data = "hello world"``` on my js, I still get the same error on the console

Comment: because it seems it loads different file - without `var data = '''`. Change text in HTML and see if it change in browser.

Comment: You can also rename `index.html` on disk to see if render_template("index.html") will have problem to load it.

Comment: @furas render template is rending my html file just fine, but it seems the data isn't there

Comment: Did you change text in HTML ? Maybe you have two files with the same text - and one without `data` and you always read version without `data`. I have no other ideas because it looks like loading wrong file.

Comment: @furas You were right

Comment: Not sure what to do now, since this question is answered.

Comment: you can describe solution as answer and later you can accept your own answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I had 2 index.html files and I was using the wrong one